# How to notify an EditText that spans have changed without re-reading the entire string

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm writing an Android app that syntax highlights code. Currently, the app works by taking a string, turning it into a `new SpannableStringBuilder`, then coloring it via `setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(...))` based on the file extension. When all that is done, `EditText.setText` is called with the builder. The problem with this approach is with large files, all of the `setSpan` calls take a pretty long time, and the UI freezes for 10s of seconds before `setText()` is called and the text is displayed.

I want to overhaul the approach here. I would like to call `setText()` on the entire string first, so the text is displayed immediately (but is uncolored). Then I want to color the text in batches of 500 lines, flushing to the display after each batch. The user probably won't notice any difference (aside from the perf) because I can process + flush 500 lines much faster than the user can scroll down 500 lines.

I'm not sure how to implement my idea efficiently, however. The only way to 'flush' the changes by updating the display is to call `setText()` on the `SpannableStringBuilder` again after appending more spans to it. `setText()`, in turn, re-reads through the entire string and all its spans, when it only needs to look at the new spans. Is it possible to tell the `EditText` to only redraw the new spans? Thanks.

Comment: Also you should probably offload the span building to a separat thread to avoid blocking the UI thread

Comment: @Ahmad Good idea, I will consider that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being dumb. I made this test app (using Xamarin / C#) before asking this question:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    var editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.EditText);
    var ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(new string('E', 250));
    editText.SetText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.Editable);
    ssb.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Blue), 0, ssb.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveExclusive);
}
```

When you run the app all of the text is white. I thought this was because the `EditText` disregards any changes you made after `SetText`, and you need to call `SetText` again for the changes to take effect. However, I remembered that `EditText` by default copies your `Editable` when you call `SetText`, so you have to add this beforehand:

```
editText.SetEditableFactory(new NoCopyEditableFactory());

private class NoCopyEditableFactory : EditableFactory // Editable.Factory in Java
{
    public override IEditable NewEditable(ICharSequence source) => (IEditable)source;
}
```

Now all of the text is blue even though I called `SetSpan` after `SetText`.